# firebase_storage object-not-found No object exists at the desired reference

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

Can anyone help me with the above error.

following is the code.

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {
  static AuthController instance = Get.find();

  late Rx<File?> _pickedImage;

  File? get ProfilePhoto => _pickedImage.value;

  void pickImage() async {
    final pickedImage =
        await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      Get.snackbar('Profile Picture',
          'You have successfully selected your profile picture');
    }
    _pickedImage = Rx<File?>(File(pickedImage!.path));
  }

  // upload to firebase storage
  Future<String> _uploadToStorage(File image) async {
    Reference ref = firebaseStorage
        .ref()
        .child('profilePics')
        .child(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid);

    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(image);
    TaskSnapshot snap = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  // registering the user
  void registerUser(
      String username, String email, String password, File? image) async {
    try {
      if (username.isNotEmpty &&
          email.isNotEmpty &&
          password.isNotEmpty &&
          image != null) {
        // save out user to our ath and firebase store
        UserCredential cred = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
        String downloadUrl = await _uploadToStorage(image);
        model.User user = model.User(
          name: username,
          email: email,
          uid: cred.user!.uid,
          profilePhoto: downloadUrl,
        );
        await firestore
            .collection('users')
            .doc(cred.user!.uid)
            .set(user.toJson());
      } else {
        Get.snackbar(
          'Error Creating Account',
          'Please enter all the details',
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar(
        'Error Creating Account',
        e.toString(),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I was trying to create authcontroller to set user details on firbease storage.

This are the constant which I have used.

Please let me know if need any more information. I am stuck and need help, thanks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe dumb question but.. did you enable Storage on the console (or simulator)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what causes the error, you should start by changing your _uploadtostorage function to catch some errors, as

```
Future<String> _uploadToStorage(File image) async {


try {
    Reference ref = firebaseStorage
        .ref()
        .child('profilePics')
        .child(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid);
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(image);
    TaskSnapshot snap = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
} catch (e) {
    print('Error uploading image to Firebase Storage: $e');
    throw e; 
  }
}
```

Try this and see if any other error messages appear.